# Flask + uwsgi + nginx: When is memory released?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building an API with Flask.

If I have, for example, a Flask route like this one:

```
@app.route('/api/tasks', methods=['GET'])
@auth.login_required
def tasks():
    tasks = g.user.tasks
    task_list = []
    for t in tasks:
        d = {}
        d['name'] = t.name
        d['id'] = t.id
        task_list.append(d)
    return jsonify({'tasks':task_list})
```

Will the memory used by the variables "tasks" and "task_list" be released right after the response is returned?

In my case, it seems that the uwsgi processes are not releasing the memory they use for each request, at least it seems they are not doing it right after each return.

The tasks are retrieved from a MySQL db by using the Flask-SQLAlchemy extension.

Thanks!

EDIT:
This is my uwsgi config file (/etc/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.ini):

```
[uwsgi]
master = true
die-on-term = true
processes = 1
threads = 2
logger = file:/var/log/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.log
```

And I call it like:

```
uwsgi  --socket 127.0.0.1:8080 -w wsgi:app --ini /etc/flask-uwsgi/flask-uwsgi.ini --stats /tmp/statsock --memory-report
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `tasks` and `task_list` are local variables, and these will be unbound when the view function returns.

If the *memory for their contents* is released depends on other wether or references to the data exist. Python objects are cleared when their reference count drops to 0, so if anything *else* still references objects outside of this function then they will not be cleared.

For example, the `task_list` list object has no other references, and will be cleared immediately. The list contains new `dict` objects (referenced by `d` in the loop) and these also have no other references so will be cleared. These dictionaries contain strings for the keys; these are reused (they are interned in this case and there is only one copy of each string object) and don't need to be cleared.

That leaves the `t.name` and `t.id` values, as well as the `g.user.tasks` reference; if `g.user.task` is a list object then `g.user.task` is reference to that object and it won't be cleared. Any of the `t.name` and `t.id` values could also still be referenced elsewhere, and stay around. This is a good thing however, usually.